# What are the [-] in bash parameter?

Tags: bash

I seen some "minus" (i.e : "-" ) parameters on some bash commands, what do they mean?

Here for example there are 2:

one for `wget -q -O - http` and one for `tar -xzf - -C`

```
 wget -q -O - http://apache.mirrors.pair.com/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.9/zookeeper-3.4.9.tar.gz | tar -xzf - -C /opt2
```

Comment: When you see a hyphen alone, it generally refers to `stdin` or `stdout`. In the case of your `wget` example, the command is telling `wget` to send its output (`-O`) to stdout quietly (`-q`), and in the case of your `tar` command, you will use stdin as the file (`-f`) from which tar will extract (`-x`) compressed (`-z`) content into some directory (`-C`). Note that this is a general usage question rather than a programming question, so I've voted to close it. You might want to just delete it yourself to avoid further downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a convention that many programs follow. `-` usually refers to `stdin` and `stdout`.

Try `man wget`:

```
-O file
--output-document=file
    The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all
    will be concatenated together and written to file.  If - is used as
    file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link
    conversion.  (Use ./- to print to a file literally named -.)
```

So, if `-` is used, documents will be printed to the standard output.